# Passing struct to vector, printing vector gives weird results

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Consider the following program. Essentially I have a `struct` called Person, which is defaulted to contain `name="NO NAME"` and `age = 0`. Now I first create a vector that adds 5 `Person` to it. Even ran in the debugger, after the for loop ends its just a 5 size vector, with default `Person`. However when I go to print it, something goes wrong.

I first of all pass in `const` vector since I am not changing anything. Using `printf`, I do this: `list_of_persons.at(i).name, list_of_persons.at(i).age`, to just print out the person's name and age. You would expect it to be `NO NAME` and `0`, since I have not changed the default value, but my cmd gives me something way different, and I don't know why?

[image]

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main();

struct Person {
    string name = "NO NAME";
    int age = 0;
};

void print_vector(const vector <Person> &);

int main()
{
    vector<Person> list_of_persons;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        struct Person p;
        list_of_persons.push_back(p);
    }
    print_vector(list_of_persons);

    printf("\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void print_vector(const vector<Person>& list_of_persons)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < list_of_persons.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("Person %d \n", i);
        printf("Name: %s\nAge: %d \n \n", list_of_persons.at(i).name, list_of_persons.at(i).age);
    }
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are _different languages_!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're mixing C++ with `printf` C function. `printf` cannot know that you're passing something else than a string here because arguments of `printf` are *variable* and the function "trusts" the formatting string & the caller for providing proper types.

What you see is the `char *` representation of the `std::string` object: binary data/garbage when printed as-is (and also trashes the `age` argument because of incorrect argument size)

You should use `std::cout` from `iostream` which recognizes `std::string` type properly. Like this for instance:

```
std::cout << "Name: " << list_of_persons.at(i).name << "\nAge: " << list_of_persons.at(i).age << "\n \n";
```

If you want to stick to `printf`, you have to get the pointer on the underlying `const char *` using `c_str()`

```
printf("Name: %s\nAge: %d \n \n", list_of_persons.at(i).name.c_str(), list_of_persons.at(i).age);
```